# Is there a difference between the pins in the Arduino UNO Ethernet and the Ethernet shield?

Tags: arduino, ethernet

I just bought an Arduino UNO Ethernet R3, have been looking for projects that use it but can only find projects that use the old basic Arduino with an additional Ethernet shield. Any major differences between the two that become relevant when using these shield projects as a guide?

Comment: Have you tried the Arduino forum?

Comment: No, didn't know that existed. Found it now though :)

Comment: [Or the board reference:](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arduino Ethernet doesn't have a USB connector, so you must program the board via external ISP; the principle is the same. Using an Ethernet shield on top of an Arduino board has many advantages; e.g., we can have more pins when the shield removed and the device has a USB connector. Remember that pins 10-13 are used by the Mega328 to communicate with the W5100, so these pins cannot be used when Ethernet mode is on.

Comment: That's not quite true; the [web page](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardEthernet) says that you can use an ordinary USB-to-serial adapter to program the board. If you use ISP, you lose the Arduino bootloader.